# Custom route in Rails for searching by field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to add a route to Rails app, so I can search by other field than id (and still be able to search by id)

```
def bycode
  @plot = Plot.find_by_code(params[:code])
  respond_to do |format|
    if !plot.nil?
      format.json {render json: @plot}
    else
      format.json
    end
  end
end
```

and in routes.rb:

```
resources :plots do
  get 'bycode/:code' => 'plots#bycode'
end
```

in $ rake routes I get:

```
GET    /plots/:plot_id/bycode/:code(.:format) plots#bycode
```

I just want to be able to do

```
http://myapp.com/plots/bycode?code=codename
```

or something similar

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use the RESTful route (`http://myapp.com/plots/<code>`)

and in your controller

```
@plot = Plot.where(code: params[:id]).first || Plot.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: but http://myapp.com/plots?code=codename  just takes me to plots#index and want to retain the option to use common plots/:id path

Comment: I see, there's only one plot with any given code... this should be a `#show` type route...

Comment: That worked! However for some reason had to do     @plot =Plot.find_by_code(params[:id])  ||  Plot.find(params[:id])
instead (was failing otherwise).